# Search through List of list recursively and return index position in original list

Tags: python, recursion

Title says most of the problem. **WE ARE REQUIRED TO WRITE THIS RECURSIVELY**. We are given a list of presidents:

```
    preslst=[['George Washington',1732,1788],['John Adams',1735,1796],['Thomas Jefferson',1743,1800],['James Madison',1751,1808],
     ['James Monroe',1758,1816],['John Quincy Adams',1767,1824],['Andrew Jackson',1767,1828],['Martin Van Buren',1782,1836],
     ['William Henry Harrison',1773,1840],['John Tyler',1790,1840],['James K. Polk',1795,1844],['Zachary Taylor',1784,1848],
  ['Millard Fillmore',1800,1850],['Franklin Pierce',1804,1858],['James Buchanan',1791,1857],['Abraham Lincoln',1809,1861],
     ['Andrew Johnson',1808,1865],['Ulysses S. Grant',1822,1869],['Rutherford B. Hayes',1822,1877],['James A. Garfield',1831,1881],
     ['Chester A. Arthur',1829,1881],['Grover Cleveland',1837,1885],['Benjamin Harrison',1833,1889],['Grover Cleveland',1837,1893],
     ['William McKinley',1843,1897],['Theodore Roosevelt',1858,1901],['William Howard Taft',1857,1909],['Woodrow Wilson',1856,1913],
     ['Warren G. Harding',1865,1921],['Calvin Coolidge',1872,1923],['Herbert Hoover',1874,1929],['Franklin D. Roosevelt',1882,1933],
     ['Harry S. Truman',1884,1945],['Dwight D. Eisenhower',1890,1953],['John F. Kennedy',1917,1961],['Lyndon B. Johnson',1908,1963],
     ['Richard M. Nixon',1913,1969],['Gerald Ford',1913,1974],['Jimmy Carter',1924,1977],['Ronald Reagan',1911,1981],
     ['George H. Bush',1924,1989],['Bill Clinton',1946,1993],['George H.W. Bush',1946,2001],['Barack Obama',1961,2009],
     ['Donald Trump',1946,2017]]
```

We are asked to define a function (arg1 = presidents name as formatted in the list, arg2 = preslst) that will recursively go through the list and return the index position of the list that holds the right name.

This is what I have currently:

```
def presPosition(pres,preslst):
    for i in range(0,len(preslst)):
        print('search')
        presname = preslst[i][0]

        if presname ==  pres:
            print("FOUND")
            foundpres = preslst[0]
            return preslst.index(foundpres)

        else:
            return presPosition(pres,preslst[1:])
```

Ex: presPosition('John Adams',preslst) the returned value should be 1.

I keep getting 0 as the returned value, and I understand why because the preslst being passed in the else statement will have the name I'm looking for as the first item in the passed list. So how do I get the function to return the position of the where it is in the original list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the recursion?  Don't do that...

Comment: Lol I know right? FYI its homework, and were required to use recursion for the functions.

Comment: You have a for loop in which all paths do a return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting `0` because after each iteration you pass `preslst[1:]` to the next iteration. And you return `preslst.index(foundpres)` which is from the above list and its always the 0th index.

Instead I suggest follow.

```
def presPosition(pres,preslst, next_index=0):
    print('search')
    if next_index == len(preslst):
        print("NOT FOUND")
        return

    presobj = preslst[next_index]
    presname = presobj[0]

    if presname ==  pres:
        print("FOUND")
        return preslst.index(presobj)    # return next_index

    else:
        return presPosition(pres,preslst, next_index+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below if you need recursion.

```
def presPosition(pres, preslst, i=0):
    if i == len(preslst):
        return "Pres Not Found!"

    if preslst[i][0] == pres:
        return i
    else:

        return presPosition(pres, preslst, i+=1)
```

In your code, you are removing the first element, therefore your index will always be 0.

Comment: Sorry I should've stated that its a homework assignment and we are required to write this with recursion. :( 

I understand why its doing it. I just don't know how to do this another way.

Comment: You can do recursion but don't change the initial list or make copy of the original list.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it with `enumerate()` and a `for-loop`:

```
 def myFunc(pname, plist)    
    presname = pname
    preslist = plist
    for index, tup in enumerate(plist):
        if tup[0] == pname:
            return index
        raise ValueError('value not found in list')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird exercise and definitely not fit for recursion. However, here's something you could do. Return the length of the list when you find the element and at the end you subtract it from the original list's size:

```
def presPosition(pres,preslst):
    print('search')
    presname = preslst[0][0]

    if presname ==  pres:
        print("FOUND")
        return len(preslst)

    else:
        return presPosition(pres,preslst[1:])

preslst = [...] # your list
print(len(preslst) - presPosition('James Madison', preslst)) # outputs 3
```

BTW, you don't need the for loop as you're only using the first element and then returning, so I removed it.

Comment: I agree with you completely haha. I like where your head is at, but it needs to be one function.